# How to retrieve a JWT Token (Bearer Token) from any [Authorize] request in C# Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, authorization

I need to redeem the authorization token of my API requests so that I can decode and verify the role that the user has (since I put this value in the claim of the token).

I don't have the slightest idea how to do it, I know that there is Identity users with SQL Server that makes this operation much easier. But in my case I want to make a simple and small application and I can only use the MySQL database,

I believe in advance any help.

Here is my authentication method in case it helps

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public IActionResult Auth([FromBody] AuthRequestModel authRequest)
{
    var checkUsuario = (_dataBaseContext.Usuario
        .Include(u => u.Cargo)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Email == authRequest.Usuario).Result
    );

    if (checkUsuario == null) 
         return NotFound("usuario nao encontrado");

    var hash = new Hash(SHA256.Create());
    var senhaCorreta = hash.VerificarSenha(authRequest.Senha, checkUsuario.Senha);

    if (!senhaCorreta)
        return BadRequest("Senha incorreta");

    var userData = new {
        checkUsuario.Nome, 
        checkUsuario.Sobrenome, 
        checkUsuario.Id
    }; 

    var jwt = Request.Headers["Bearer"];
    var token = TokenService.GenerateToken(checkUsuario); 
    var response = new {userData, Token = token, jwt}; 

    return Ok(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication validation (are you allowed to access an endpoint) should be implemented in middleware, so that it occurs on all end points that have the [Authorize] attibute, not on any particular end point.  The database you use is irrelevant because the JWT token is not required to be checked against a database at this point (It is 'generated' by the server, which MAY include reading the permissions from the database, but that can be done with MySql,MsSql,Oracle,anything).

This is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

I validate the JWT header token in my WEB APIs request in the code section, you can also do the same way.

User Profile `Model`

```
 public class UserProfile
        {
            public string UserId { get; set; }
    
        }
```

In Web API code, read the header from Http **Request** and validate with **null** check and extract the `JWT`

```
UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
if (Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
                {
                    userProfile = GetTokenById(Request.Headers.Authorization, out jwt);
                    var emailId = userProfile.UserId;
                    var tokenCode = jwt;
                    if (IsNullOrEmpty(tokenCode))
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, MapperService.CreateErrorModel("Error Code", "Token is not valid"));
                }
```

`GetTokenById` Method for parsing the JWT and bind the User Profile Model

```
private UserProfile GetTokenById(AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization, out string jwt)
        {
            UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
            var txtJwtIn = string.Empty;
            if (authorization != null)
            {
                txtJwtIn = authorization.Parameter;
                var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var readableToken = jwtHandler.CanReadToken(txtJwtIn);

                if (readableToken)
                {
                    var token = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(txtJwtIn);
                    var claims = token.Claims;
                    foreach (var c in claims)
                    {
                        if(c.Type == "emails")
                        {
                            userProfile.UserId = c.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            jwt = txtJwtIn;
            return userProfile;
        }
```